# I need to download the image from URL and save into the folder in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

It's working perfect on local machine but when I upload the same code into the AWS server, its downloading only 1kb of image and its not readable? I need the whole image from URL. Please let me know how to resolve this issue?

```
print('Download Starting...')

url = 'https://hotpoptoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/9062079d.jpg'

req = requests.get(url, stream=True)


with open("9062079d.jpg",'wb') as output_file:
    for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=1025):
        if chunk:
            output_file.write(chunk)

print('Download Completed!!!')
```

Comment: There isn't anything magical or specific to AWS or requests here that should make a difference. Do you have enough free space? How are you determining that you only have 1kb of data? Do you know if it is the first 1kb or some other part? You are using a rather unconventional chunk size, by the way. Have you tried any of my other suggestions from my answer at [How to download image using requests](//stackoverflow.com/a/13137873)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply just use like that

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url_to_your_image, "folders_name/saved_image.jpg")
```

if you want to create the folder before saving

```
os.mkdir('folder_name')
```